# Arduino IDE is not showing any port macOS

Tags: macos, arduino, arduino-uno, robotics, arduino-ide

My **Arduino Uno** is plugged in with mac USB port. But Arduino IDE is not showing any port.
(macOS- Catalina)

[image]

Comment: is it a genuine arduino or knock off?

Comment: Genuine. I worked with it before, it was fine. But after reseting the OS it's showing like this.

Comment: Did you try switching usb ports?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work.

Comment: does it work with a fresh uno?

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Comment: usb ports otherwise functional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add to Nikhil Borle's answer, if you check the USB Devices in the System Report and don't see anything, you may have a cable problem. I didn't see my device, and found out that the USB Type-B cable wasn't fully plugged in to my Arduino! (It has been a very long time since I've used Type-B). Apparently it's possible to plug it in halfway and it will still receive power, but won't be able to communicate...

Once I fixed that, I closed & reopened System Information and it showed up as simply "Communication Device", although when I selected that, under the details, "Manufacturer" was listed as "Arduino ([www.arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc))" (I've got an Arduino Uno R3).

Comment: honestly, +1 for this answer...I am using an Elegoo Arduino knockoff and the included USB Type-B cable head is a little bit snug, so it would still transfer power without being plugged all the way in. After I pushed it all the way in I was able to see the device show up in the Port list.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Arduino Leonardo knock off on OS X Ventura on an M1 MacBook Pro. When plugging in the board into USB I noticed some UI window appearing and disappearing quickly. Too quick to identify what is it. Leonardo appeared in System Report, but not in Arduino IDE.

After shorting RST to GND a few times while connected, I finally got a window asking confirmation to "connect the accessory" to Mac. Once I approved, it connected fine from then on.

There is a setting in System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Security -> Allow accessories to connect. It can be set to a less restrictive setting.

[image: Allow accessories to connect]

Comment: can you please share the security concerns of mac with that permission

Comment: As soon as I changed the setting to Automatically When Unlocked then the device was visible in the system report and available in the Arduino IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try unplugging everything from the Arduino except for the USB cable.

I had a similar problem with Arduino Uno and Mac Catalina 10.15.7. After try multiple solutions I noticed the green on light on my Uno was very faint or kept turning off. After playing with the board for a minute I unplugged all the wires for my project so that only the USB cable was plugged into the Uno and nothing else. After that the Arduino showed in the port menu as expected.

[image: Arduino shows in port menu correctly]

Apparently the setup of my project was causing some kind of short that prevented the Uno from starting up properly, or was causing a reboot.

Comment: "Try unplugging everything from the Arduino except for the USB cable." - that's it for me. Cable must be plugged in first then connect Arduino.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by installing the FTDI VCP driver from the FTDI Chip website.

Specifically, my Arduino Duemilanove wouldn't show up under macOS Big Sur (11.4); all I'd see was /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port. But the board showed up under System Information as FT232R USB UART, so I knew the cable was working. Installing the driver fixed it, and now the Arduino shows up as /dev/cu.usbserial-... as expected.

Comment: Same. Downloaded the latest driver from https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/ and now the IDE detects my ports and my Arduino Mega.

Comment: Just leaving a reference to those FTDI drivers in regards to Arduino: https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/4411305694610-Install-or-update-FTDI-drivers

Answer (score 1):

Had suffered through this same prob for a bit, and read all the advice. Yeah, yeah - tried different computers and checked the cables… or so I thought. Got buried in the 'double reset' and the 32u4 spec. But...

Beware that a cable may appear okay and functional, but there are some USB micro cables that are power-only and no data. So LED's may light up and convince you that it's okay, but in reality there's no data connection.

A little thing, but it's easy to breeze by that and not realize that the USB logo is thrown around pretty freely these days, and you're not always getting what you think you are, in the cable department.  FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If your usb cable or arduino board isn't damaged, then it's most probably the drivers for usb connectivity.
My uno had the same problems which turned out that it used the CH340 chip for usb connectivity and it's drivers weren't installed.

[Link here](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html#:%7E:text=The%20CH340%20chip%20is%20used,log%2C%20and%20much%20less%20painful.)!

After installing the drivers, everything was fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. ch340 drivers issue for me. Its working now

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur due to two main reasons.

1. Your computer does not recognize your Arduino board
2. Your Arduino Board is damaged

Sometimes your computer does not recognize your arduino board. You can check it by opening **Device Manager > Other Devices** If a device named Arduino Uno is there, probably it is due to the driver issue.
You can solve it by manually configuring the driver [from here.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/DriverInstallation/)

If the Arduino Board is still not recognized, it can be due to a damaged cable or the Arduino board is damaged. Try using a different cable to connect it to your computer. If the board is still not recognized, the Arduino board might be damaged, You may have to repair the damaged board by giving it to a shop or may have to buy a new board which seems the easier way.

Comment: New cable did the trick! Ty

Comment: Device Manager is a Windows component, not MacOS. Unfortunately I have not found a solution to this issue either and I'm resorting to looking for an old Windows PC. Seems USB 3.0 ports are not supported either

Comment: The question specifies MacOS, device manager is windows only.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem for some time.
The following combination wouldn't work: MacOS Catalina, Arduino IDE, NODEMCU.
While MacOS Catalina, Arduino IDE, Arduino UNO continued to work.
I did the following:

- I checked the "USB" devices in the MacOS System report and it would show the connected USB-UART device whenever I connected the NODEMCU.
- This was also evidence that my cable was not faulty. That gave me the clue to look into drivers. I am using NODEMCU V1.0 AMICA
- I found [https://cityos-air.readme.io/docs/1-mac-os-usb-drivers-for-nodemcu]
- Installed the driver and ARDUINO IDE immediately started showing the USB port connected to the NODEMCU. I was able to upload a sketch immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively often I met the same problem at Arduino MKR1000.
Solution - connect the RESET pin on the board to the GND pin (i.e. Ground). For about a second or more. It should restart properly.
It looks like this works as hard reset while Reset button is only soft reset.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the serial port was detected initially after installing VCP driver but after a few days serial stops appearing. I checked the cable, re-install the driver and restart PC but no use. Finally, I had to press the reset button on board for 30 sec and the serial started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: my MacBook Air registered by Arduino Board in the USB Device Tree but it was not showing up in the Ports list of the Arduino IDE. It was resolved when I changed the Privacy and Security setting for Allow Accessories to Connect. When I changed the setting to "Automatically When Unlocked" the Arduino IDE was able to recognize my board.

Route to setting: Apple Logo on top Right -> System Settings -> Privacy and Security -> (scroll down to Security) Allow Accessories to Connect.